# Prove that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\alpha\in\mathbb C$. Recall that $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ = {${f(\alpha) : f(X) \in \mathbb Q[X]}$} and that $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is a vector space over $\mathbb Q$.

Suppose that $\mathbb Q[\alpha]$ is finite dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb Q$. Prove that $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb Q$.

I'm not sure where to start with this proof, so any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Let $n = \mathrm{dim}_{\mathbb{Q}}(\mathbb{Q}[\alpha])$ and note that the elements $1, \alpha, \alpha^2, \dots, \alpha^n \in \mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$.